# ffmpeg filter_complex chaining video streams (watermark then trim and join)

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to add watermark and then trim specific part and at last join these by following command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i test_video.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]drawtext=fontfile=Lato-light.ttf:text='test':fontcolor=white:fontsize=20:x=0:y=h-th[outv]; \
[outv]trim=2:5[v1];[outv]trim=7:9[v2];[v1][v2]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[out]" \
-map '[out]' test_video_text.mp4
```

but no success and get the following error:

```
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.0.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid --enable-libfreetype --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
  libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
  libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test_video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp41mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2015-09-24 18:32:33
  Duration: 00:00:09.87, start: 0.068254, bitrate: 235 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 320x320, 183 kb/s, 29.67 fps, 29.67 tbr, 29673 tbn, 59.35 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-09-24 18:32:33
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (HE-AAC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 48 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-09-24 18:32:33
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fff43000000] Invalid stream specifier: outv.
    Last message repeated 1 times
Stream specifier 'outv' in filtergraph description [0:v]drawtext=fontfile=Lato-Light.ttf:text='test':fontcolor=white:fontsize=20:x=0:y=h-th[outv]; [outv]trim=2:4[v1];[outv]trim=6:8[v2];[v1][v2]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[out] matches no streams.
```

kindly someone guide me what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`outv` has already been routed once, to the first trim. Use split:

```
ffmpeg -y -i test_video.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]drawtext=fontfile=Lato-light.ttf:text='test':fontcolor=white:fontsize=20:x=0:y=h-th[outv]; \
[outv]split[o1][o2]; \
[o1]trim=2:5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; \
[o2]trim=7:9,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2]; \
[v1][v2]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[out]" \
-map '[out]' test_video_text.mp4
```